# Should I use android LocationManager.getBestProvider every time I ask for location updates?

Tags: android, android-mapview, locationmanager

I'm using Google APIs and the MapActivity, MapView etc..
When I need to get my current location I use this code the FIRST TIME :

```
myLocationManager =(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
// Sets the criteria for a fine and low power provider
Criteria crit = new Criteria();
crit.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
crit.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);    
// Gets the best matched provider, and only if it's on
String provider = myLocationManager.getBestProvider(crit, true);
// If there are no location providers available
if (provider == null){
    OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Closes the activity
            finish();
        }
    };
    Utils.getInstance().showAlertDialog(this, R.string.warning_dialog_title,
                               R.string.no_location_providers_error_message,
                            android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert, false, listener);
}
// Location services is enabled
else{
    myLocationListener = new MyLocationListener();
    myLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            provider,
            0,
            0,
            myLocationListener);        
    // TODO - put a marker in my location       
    GeoPoint currentGeoPoint = MapUtils.getInstance().
            getCurrentLocation(myLocationManager, provider);        
    // Center to the current location
    centerLocation(currentGeoPoint, MAX_ZOOM);
}
```

I also have a "back to current location button" - for when the user moves the map around and wants to quickly return to his current location.

My question is,
should I use the `getBestProvider()` method *each time* I want to get location information?

I could save the last choosen provider, but the conditions could change every second:

1. User turned off GPS
2. No GPS signal
3. NETWORK_PROVIDER is better in the current situation
4. etc..

What is the right approach?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-in-a/3145655#3145655. Check the link. You may find answers to your questions.

Comment: This still doesn't answer my question. My code also works. But should I or should I not call the getBestProvider each time? In my opinion yes..

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#BestEstimate. You probably should go through this link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like been told on the coments,
this is the answer:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#BestEstimate

Comment: Broken link. That's why posting links as answers is bad!

Answer (score 0):

You could always use this , but make sure to check on the **Location.getTime()** -> this would tell you the time it was fixed and so you can easily differentiate between the fresh and stale location fixes.